# Import a pandas dataframe in a Streamlit app

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I am trying to import a pandas dataframe in a Streamlit app (the goal being to run a Machine Learning model based on this dataframe when clicking a button). I use the usual way:

```
import pandas as pd
import streamlit as st
df = pd.read_csv('/data/metabolic_syndrome.csv')
if (st.button('Click on this fancy button !')):
    st.warning("This was a bad choice.")
```

My path is the good one on my local machine, yet when I run the app on `localhost` it sends back this error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/data/metabolic_syndrome.csv'

I may miss a key concept as I'm not a computer science specialist (such as saving the file somewhere else) yet the pathfile is the good one on my local machine, and I really don't understand what should I do here to have a proper import and run the app localy ? If that's useful, I'm on `iOS`.

Comment: Do you have your csv file in your working directory?

Comment: Absolutely. I forgot to mention, but the pathfile is not the problem.

Comment: What makes you think it's not the problem? Until you show your working environment structure, I don't think someone can help. We can only guess.

Comment: not sure as you said your are on ios (and I don't no much of this), but if the folder `data` is in the same folder than your python program, then try with a `.` before the first slash `/`

Comment: Right click on the csv file in your working environment and `copy relative path` and replace the path you entered for `df` with the one you copied to see if that helps.

Comment: The absolute path file works, but not the relative one (albeit I've tried everything and I am absolutely sure about its specification, even when trying @Ben.T's solution)

Answer (score 0):

Try with a dot, like this:

```
pd.read_csv('./data/metabolic_syndrome.csv')
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help ; unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt your path to how you launch streamlit.exe.
This should work:

```
cd PATH_TO_PROJECT_DIR
PATH_TO_STREAMLIT\streamlit.exe run main.py --server.port 8080
```

Of course, your data folder must be a subfolder of PROJECT_DIR.

In your code, like stated before, you then need the . for relative path:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./data/metabolic_syndrome.csv')
```